# square roots and limits

Tags: complex-analysis

I am dealing with a function $f(z)$ defined implicitly on the upper half plane $\{z:\Im z>0\}$ by the equation
$$2f^2 + zf + 1 =0.$$
This equation has 2 roots, and the solution $f$ should be the one with the following property: if $\Im z>0$, then $\Im f(z)>0$.

Afterwards, I would like to compute the limits of $f$ on the real axis, more precisely, the limits $f(x) := \lim_{y \downarrow 0} f(x+iy)$.

Here is what I find:

1. $f(z) = \frac{-z+\sqrt{z^2-8}}{4}$, where $\sqrt{z}$ is chosen to have positive imaginary part if $\Im z>0$.
2. If $|z|\le 2\sqrt{2}$, then the limit $f(x) = \frac{-x+i\sqrt{8-x^2}}{4}$.
3. If $x = -3$, then the limit $f(x) = 1$.

Is that correct ? I believe the third property should be wrong because it leads to some nonsensical conclusion for me, so I suspected maybe it was one of those branch cut issues.

Thank you!

**Edit:** Here is the context of the problem. If you consider the adjacency matrix $A$ of the infinite $3$-regular tree, it is well-known that the spectrum $\sigma(A) = [-2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2}]$. On the other hand, using the resolvent identity, you can show that the Green's function $G(z) = \langle \delta_o, (A-zI)^{-1}\delta_o \rangle$ satisfies $G(z) = \frac{-1}{z+3f(z)}$ in the upper-half plane, where $f(z)$ is a function that satisfies $2f^2+zf+1=0$. If $-3$ was an isolated pole of $G(z)$, it would mean that $-3\in \sigma(A)$ and in fact an eigenvalue, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the equation.

Comment: What's wrong with the limit equal $1$ ?

Comment: The problem is that $G(z) = \frac{-1}{z + 3 f(z)}$ would then explode as $z \to -3$. This $G(z)$ is some Green's function, and it is well-known in the present context that the spectrum of the underlying operator is $[-2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2}]$. So $G(-3)$ should exist.

Comment: I have added the context in more detail in the question.

Comment: If I remember well if the tree is of order $q+1$ then the spectrum is equal $[-2\sqrt{q},2\sqrt{q}].$ How do you get the equation ? Do you rely on $$(zI-A)^{-1}-(wI-A)^{-1}=-(z-w)(zI-A)^{-1}(wI-A)^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes, that's the spectrum. I used the other resolvent identity involving two operators, the first operator being the adjacency matrix on the full tree, the second operator being the adjacency matrix on a subtree. You can find more details for example in the book of Aizenman and Warzel "Random operators. Disorder effects and quantum spectra and dynamics", p. 254-256.

Comment: Now that you made me look at the book, they say that for real $x$ with $|x|>2\sqrt{2}$, we should have $f(x) = \frac{-x+sgn(x)\sqrt{x^2-8}}{4}$. In that case $f(-3) = \frac{1}{2}$ and there is no problem. The question is where does this $sgn(x)$ come from?

Comment: Perhaps the function should be odd. It may follow from the identity that adjacency matrix $A$  satisfies $AD=-DA$ where $D\delta_x=(-1)^n\delta_x,$ where $n$ denotes the distance of the vertex $x $ to a fixed vertex $x_0.$ The way I would get the equation is to study the recurrence relation associated with $A=A_1$ and the adjacency matrix $A_n$ of degree $n$

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got it; it is indeed a "branch cut issue". If we write all details things become clear. I will follow the book "Complex Analysis" of Moore and Hadlock, Ex. 10.7.4., page 341. I will also consider the slightly more general case where the equation is $qf^2+zf+1=0$.

Let $w_1 = \sqrt{r} e^{i\theta/2}$ and $w_2 = \sqrt{s} e^{i\phi/2}$, where $r = |z-2\sqrt{q}|$, $s=|z+2\sqrt{q}|$, $\theta = \arg(z-2\sqrt{q})$ and $\phi = \arg(z+2\sqrt{q})$. For $w_1$ we consider the branch cut $[2\sqrt{q},\infty)$, so the argument $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$. For $w_2$ we consider the branch cut $(-\infty,-2\sqrt{q}]$. This means the argument $\phi$ will now take values in $(-\pi,\pi]$. Here $w_1$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ minus the first branch while $w_2$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ minus the second branch. So the product $g = w_1w_2$ is analytic in the intersection, $D = \mathbb{C} \setminus ((-\infty,-2\sqrt{q}]\cup [2\sqrt{q},\infty))$. Clearly $g$ is a root of $z^2-4q$, i.e. $g^2 = rs e^{i(\phi+\theta)} = z^2-4q$. Moreover, if $z\in\mathbb{C}^+$, the upper half plane, then $\theta,\phi\in(0,\pi)$, so $g$ has positive imaginary part as required. Let us now compute the limit as $z = x+iy \downarrow x$.

If $x>2\sqrt{q}$, then as $z = x+iy \downarrow x$, we have $\theta \downarrow 0$ and $\phi\downarrow 0$. Hence, $g\to \sqrt{|x^2-4q|} = \sqrt{x^2-4q}$.

If $x<2\sqrt{q}$, then as $z = x+iy\downarrow x$, we have $\theta \uparrow \pi$, $\phi\uparrow \pi$. Hence, $g \to \sqrt{|x^2-4q|} e^{i\pi/2} e^{i\pi/2} = -\sqrt{x^2-4q}$.

If $|x|\le 2\sqrt{q}$, then as $z = x+iy\downarrow x$, we have $\theta \uparrow \pi$ but $\phi \downarrow 0$. Hence, $g\to \sqrt{|x^2-4q|}e^{i\pi/2} = i \sqrt{4q-x^2}$.

In particular, point (3) in my question is indeed incorrect as I suspected.

Many thanks for your useful comments. I also came accross this book from another question on this website; never really learned these things well unfortunately.